# Cassandra, schema and process design for concurrent writes

Tags: concurrency, cassandra, schema

This is a long-winded question. It is about Cassandra schema design. I'm here to get inputs from your respected experts on a use-case I'm working on. All inputs, suggestions, and critics are welcome. Here goes my question.

We would like to collect REVIEWS from our USERS about some PAPERS we are about to publish. For each paper we seek for 3 reviews. But We send out review invites to 3*2= 6 users. All 6 users can submit their reviews to our system, but only the first 3 count; and these first 3 reviewers will get reward their work.

In our Cassandra DB, there are three tables: USER, PAPER and REVIEW. The USER and PAPER tables are simple: each user corresponds to a row in the USER table with an unique USER_ID; similarly, each paper has a unique PAPER_ID in the PAPER table.

The REVIEW table looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE REVIEW(
    PAPER_ID uuid,
    USER_ID uuid,
    REVIEW_CONTENT text,
    PRIMARY KEY(PAPER_ID, USER_ID)
    );
```

We use PAPER_ID as the partition key of the REVIEW table so that all reviews of a given paper is stored in a single Cassandra row.  For each paper we have, we pick up 6 users, insert 6 entries into the REVIEW table and send out 6 invites to those users. So, for paper "P1", there are 6 entries in the REVIEW table that look like this

```
----------------------------------------------------
PAPER_ID      |  USER_ID        |  REVIEW_CONTENT  |
----------------------------------------------------
 P1           |  U1             |      null        |
----------------------------------------------------
 P1           |  U2             |      null        |
----------------------------------------------------
 P1           |  U3             |      null        |
----------------------------------------------------
 P1           |  U4             |      null        |
----------------------------------------------------
 P1           |  U5             |      null        |
----------------------------------------------------
 P1           |  U6             | This paper   ... |
 ---------------------------------------------------
 ...          |  ...            | ...              |
```

Users submit review via a web browser using http. At the backend, we use the following process to handle submitted reviews (use paper "P1" as an example):

1. Use partition key "P1" to get all 6 entries out from the REVIEW table.
2. Find out how many of these 6 entries have non-null values at the REVIEW_CONTENT column (non-null values indicate that the corresponding user has already submitted his review. For example, in the above table, user "U6" has submitted his review, while other 5 have not yet).
3. If this number >=3, we already had enough reviews, return to the current reviewer with a message like "Thanks, we already had enough reviews."
4. If this number < 2, save the current review to the corresponding entry in the REVIEW table, return to the reviewer with a message like "Your review has been accepted." (E.g. If the current reviewer is "U1", then fill the REVIEW_CONTENT column of "P1, U1" entry with the current review content.)
5. If this number =2, this is the most complicated the case as the current submission is the last one we'll accept. In this case, we first save the current review to the REVIEW table, then we find the ids of all three users that have submitted reviews (including the current user), record their ids into a transaction table to pay them rewards later.

But this process does not work. The problem is that it does not handle concurrent submissions correctly. Consider the following case: two users have already submitted their reviews, and meanwhile 3 other users are submitting their reviews via three concurrent process shown above.  At step 5, each of the three will think he is the 3rd and last submitter and insert new records into the transaction table. This leads to a double counting: a single user may be rewarded more than once for the same review he submitted.

Another problem of this process is that it may never reach to step 5. Let's say there is no submission in the REVIEW table, and 4 users submit their reviews at the same time. All of them saved their reviews at step 4. After this, later submitter will always be rejected as there are 4 accepted reviews already. But since we never reach step 5, no ids will be recorded into the transaction table and users will never get any rewards.

So here comes my question: How should I handle my use case using Cassandra as the back-end DB? Will Cassandra COUNTER help? If so, how? I have not thought through how to use COUNTER yet, but this blog (http://aphyr.com/posts/294-call-me-maybe-cassandra) warned that Cassandra COUNTER is not safe (quote "Consequently, Cassandra counters will over- or under-count by a wide range during a network partition.") Will Cassandra's Compare and Set (CAS) feature help? If so, how? Again the save blog warned that "Cassandra lightweight transactions are not even close to correct."

Answer (score 1):

Rather than creating empty entries in your review table, I would consider leaving it empty and only filling it as the reviews are submitted. To handle concurrency, add a timeuuid field as a sorting key:

```
CREATE TABLE review(
  paper_id uuid,
  submission_time timeuuid,
  user_id uuid,
  content text,
  PRIMARY KEY (paper_id, submission_time)
);
```

When a user makes their submission, add the entry to the table. Then AFTER the write is successful, query the table (on only the paper_id) and find out if the user's id is one of the first three. Respond to the user accordingly. Since you're committed to a small set of reviewers, the extra overhead of fetching all the reviews should be minimal (especially since you wouldn't need to include the content column in the query).

If you need to track who's reviewing the papers, add a set of user ids to the paper table and write the six user ids there.

Comment: I like your solution. It seems that a general design principle for Cassandra is that always appending to a table, try not to update it. 

One quick question: what happens if one reviewer X successfully submitted his review but when the next review Y fetches all the reviews, the newly submitted review by X is not included because of network delays? I imagine this could happen. Will ConsistencyLevel.ALL help?

Comment: Since your use case demands that level of consistency, I would recommend writing and reading at QUORUM. Assuming you have 3 or more replicas (standard), this will give you perfect consistency without having the brittleness of ALL.

Where you generate the timestamp also has an impact. For this case, it would probably be best to use CQL's [now()](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/timeuuid_functions_r.html) function. 

With those two considerations (and NTP), I think you should be very close to a guaranteed level of consistency.

Comment: If "very close" just doesn't cut it for you, read up on [Cassandra's new light weight transactions](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/lightweight-transactions-in-cassandra-2-0).